# Google Maps SDK for iOS How to Identify if a location is within 5 miles of current location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a list of lat/longs that represent the places I want to show on the Google Maps.
How can I check which of these places are near my current location. Something like Near Me functionality that we generally see.
I am using Google Maps SDK for iOS.
Hope the question is clear now?

Comment: Question should be clear ?

Comment: "" You(your) have "", what this mean ? .  who needs to join then ha>?

Comment: @KumarKl  Revenge by -1??

Comment: Point Noted . Wait and Watch......

Comment: Ha ha... Its k bro leave . I will put back your reputation.

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure that you have imported CoreLocation Framework**

```
 CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

 CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];

 CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];

 //Distance in Meters
```